# What's the optimal way to filter a set of entities in a lookup?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've got a lookup field on *Account* entity called *something*. Each such *Something* has a reference to an account. When my users click the magnifying glass, I want them to see a list of available *Something* records **but** filtered to view only such instances that link to the currently treated entity.

Also, I'll need to design such a filtration for *Contact* instances to only show the *Something* records that are related to the account that the currently regarded contact is a member of.

I can't decide between a plugin on *Retrieve* and some JS in *OnLoad* registering a fetchXML. All such operations will be done client-side. The solution needs only to work in CRM13 (and if possible apply some cool functionality in that version).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript & FetchXml are your best option here as with a Retrieve plugin you're taking the performance hit of executing on every retrieve regardless of whether the entity is being retrieved for the lookup.  A filtered lookup in JS only applies for those scenarios that require a change to the field on Account.

Another other good reason for using a filtered lookup in Js is they are now a supported feature in CRM 2013 as opposed to the "hack" that was required in 2011.

Some more info on `addPreSearch` and `addCustomFilter` can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addPreSearch) and there's a decent blog post providing examples [here](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com.au/blog/nathaneccles/2013/09/30/crm-2013-javascript-lookup-filtering-using-addcustomfilter).